# How to calculate Buffer pool response time for Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, buffer

How can we calculate buffer pool response time in Oracle database for monitoring purpose?

I have seen `v$buffer_pool`  and `v$buffer_pool_statistics` views, but these don't hold info related to this.

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: how would you define "buffer pool response time"? I have no clear understanding, what this could be.

Comment: It should be average read/write  response time for buffer  caches

Comment: as far as I can see these values are usually checked for physical reads on files - using `V$IOSTAT_FILE` or `V$FILESTAT`. Logical reads from memory are usually extremely fast. You could find a somehow related value using something like `select * from V$SYSMETRIC where metric_name = 'Logical Reads Per Sec';` But it is not a value I use to look at frequently.

Comment: I totally get your point. I have been asked to implement it. Will try your solution. Will update if i get something. Thanks